# Is this frame/bike suitable for a heavy rider?

Tags: frames, geometry, heavy

Here is one frame I am looking at, just for normal gravel road riding but I´m quite heavy rider currently around 331 lbs (150 kg).

Need help looking for issues with this frame.

[image: generic black e-bike 3/4 view]
[image: genric black e-bike side view]

Comment: Can you please expand on your question?   What issues are you concerned with specifically ?    Do you intend to pedal or rely on the motor ?

Comment: rely on the motor on the steepest hills. But pedal as fast as I can to gain speed for the  very long steep hills we have around here. Loose gravel, steep hills need speed. motor is a bafang ultra and 8 speed shimano altus

Comment: What brand/model of bike is it?  I can see a few things that look out of place, but difficult to judge without seeing the manufacturers ideas of the intended use

Comment: It is an unbranded chinese frame. it is intended for snow and beach riding

Answer (score 2):

I can see several problems with the frame for both the intended use of snow/sand and the proposed use of gravel.

1. Suspension is overkill in all the snow/sand/gravel scenarios.  Fat tyres already have excellent small bump compliance and in snow/sand/gravel you have no need to absorb large hits like if you were going through a rock garden.
2. The head angle looks to be very slack for snow/sand/gravel.  It looks like it would be more suited to trail riding.  The end result is lazy/floppy cornering with no benefit for the intended use cases.
3. The chainstays seem to be enormous - almost like they belong to a different bike entirely.  Manufacturers these days are continually innovating new ways to fit bigger tyres whilst keeping chain stays short to improve handling.  This looks like it would turn like a cruise liner.
4. The seat tube seems very short and very low.  You can see in the picture the seat is below the handlebars - i'm not sure from the picture that it would even be possible to achieve a good position.

Edit: Whilst not answering the question directly, I would add that suspension is likely not a good choice for a very heavy rider.  Suspension components are usually designed around an 'average' ~80kg rider.  I can tell from experience that they often don't work optimally for a very light rider (too stiff) and very likely have the opposite problem (too soft) for a very heavy rider.  With the desired use being for gravel riding i'd look for a simple well made rigid frame with high volume tyres.

Comment: You might get away with front suspension as a heavy rider, with the preload dialled all the way up, but on that bike most of the rider's weight will be on the rear suspension (even more than is usually the case)

Comment: And I suspect the low seat is based around ideas of relying mainly on the motor for cruising, and standing over rough stuff - but not designed by someone who's done much rough riding - and then they market it for gravel, probably because despite the looks it's going to suffer from big hits

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the bike looks beefy doesn't mean that it is.

Try and find a "maximum load rating" from the manufacturer - if it exists.  Many of the fancy race bikes have a max load of 70 or 80 kilos.

The extreme-look suspension is way overkill.  For a heavy rider you're better off with no suspension, which is known as a rigid bike, or just front suspension, also called a hard-tail.

Good luck with your searching - its not easy.

Comment: Which bike has a 70 or 80kg weight limit? Even Canyon’s “Ultimate CFR” frame with only 641g weight says it’s a class 1 bike with “The permissible maximum overall weight comprising rider, luggage and bicycle should not exceed 120 kg.” Same for the Scott Addict.

Answer (score 0):

My concern would be the linkage system.  I wouldn't assume the linkage bars or pivots are forged or strengthened.

If you are just rolling around fireroad/gravel roads, a regular hardtail should handle well without the concern of a bunch of small parts.